# Share data from PC to TV - no lan port (usb only)

Tags: networking, usb, nas, samba, tv

I have moved into the new unit and there is a TV with 2HDMI ports and 1USB only.

I used to stream movies from my server (Ubuntu) to my old PC via miniDLNA but since this new one is a crappy one and does not have LAN port ... is there any other way how to do that?

I was thinking about buying some cheap NAS or other smart unit, with which I would connect via USB to that TV and NAS will connect to samba on my server ...

Scenario:

*TV* -------> usb_cable -----> *NAS* -----> samba_share -----> *SERVER*

Is such scenario possible? is there any other (better) way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: The USB on most TV's are for updating the firmware on the input/main board. What's the tv model? Does your "crappy" one have wireless?

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/ph/tvs/fhdtv-m5000/ this piece of ..... crap :)

Comment: The TV may support a WIFI adapter via USB. Otherwise I'd use a third party HDMI device that you can stream DLNA to.

Comment: I have a usb wifi reciever ... but I doubt it is supported .... which HDMI device do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for a fire-stick or something similar to replace the features you have lost. I would recommend the Amazon fire-stick with Kodi (formerly known as XBMC). I believe it can also be installed on xbox-one. And a variety of other devices. It's not much bigger then a USB-WiFi adapter. It will do Samba share, DLNA, and has a repository for streaming apps. It's also pretty user friendly

http://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-install-kodi-on-a-fire-tv-or-fire-tv-stick

Comment: wow that sounds pretty cool... will gather more details about it and get back to you ... really appreciate it

Comment: Cool, lemme know how it works out.